# I am currently learning Python on codeacademy and I cant figure out what is wrong with this code

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm currently learning python on codeacademy, I'm trying to do the following in the last function of this code:

1. Define a function called get_class_average that has one argument students.
2. You can expect students to be a list containing your three students.
   First, make an empty list called results.
3. For each student item in the class list, calculate get_average(student) and then call results.append() with that result.
4. Finally, return the result of calling average() with results.
   But I keep getting this error anytime i try to run the code.

   > "Oops, try again. get_class_average([alice]) returned 80.55 instead of 91.15 as expected"

   ```
   lloyd = {
       "name": "Lloyd",
       "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
       "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
       "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
   }
   alice = {
       "name": "Alice",
       "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
       "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
       "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
   }
   tyler = {
       "name": "Tyler",
       "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
       "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
       "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
   }

   # Add your function below!
   def average(numbers):
       total = sum(numbers)
       total = float(total)
       return total / len(numbers)

   def get_average(student):
       homework = average(student["homework"])
       quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
       tests = average(student["tests"])
       return 0.1 * homework + 0.3 * quizzes + 0.6 * tests

   def get_letter_grade(score):
       if score >= 90:
           return "A"
       elif score >= 80:
           return "B"
       elif score >= 70:
           return "C"
       elif score >= 60:
           return "D"
       else:
           return "F"

   def get_class_average(students):
       students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
       results = []
       for student in students: 
           results.append(get_average(student))
           return average(results)
           print get_class_average(students)
           print get_letter_grade(get_class_average)
   ```

Comment: You're overwriting `students` in your function `get_class_average`. There's a reason why `students` is a parameter of that function.

Answer (score 0):

First: after `return "F"` you have a very inconsistent indentation. Move everything one tab left except for the first line (student =...)

Second: in the first line of `get_class_average` you erase students passed to function and write a new array. Either initialize students outside and pass them to function, or pass nothing and construct the array inside.

First is better.

Comment: Thanks. I had to copy from my codeacademy editor, thats why. I am deleting the array Students.